# Mongoose CastError when updating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have one model User.js that's defined like so :

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    UserSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        activeConnections: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room'}]
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

The Room reference is for another model in another file Room.js but I don't think it is necessary here.

My problem is that when I'm trying to update activeConnections, I have a CastError that says : Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" at path activeConnection.

Note that at the moment I'm doing the update, activeConnections is supposed to be an empty array.

So can anyone help me to solve this issue?

UPDATE:

The update operation happens in the following controller

```
var User = require('../models/User');
User.findById(#validObjectId).exec(function(err,      result) {
    var array = [#validObjectId, #validObjectId];
    var activeConnections = result.activeConnections.push(activeConnections);
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(#validObjectId, {'activeConnections': activeConnections}).exec(function(err, user) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        else
            //do something;
    });
})
```

Comment: It would appear that `activeConnections` isn't as empty as you think, and doesn't contain an objectid.

Comment: The issue won't likely be the existing content since a "cast error" is not actually seeing the existing  content in the array unless you actually retrieve it. So it's more likely the value you are trying to push into the array actually is not an `ObjectId`. Of course, nobody can actually say for sure without seeing what you are doing. And the actual code you are attempting to "update" with is completely missing from the question.

Comment: `var activeConnections = result.activeConnections.push(activeConnections);` is using `activeConnections` while it's still `undefined`. I'm assuming you mean to be pushing `array` instead? Anyway, you should be using the `$push` update operator here to add elements to `activeConnections` instead of directly manipulating the array.